# Foxpro form databinding and Next, Prev button

Tags: foxpro

I have form like below, and a .dbf (data table) which contains the same fields as the form, now I want to bind the first record to the form and implement `Next` and `Prev`... I know this seems very basic, but I can't find any page about this.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll give you the basics, then try to guide you elsewhere, and if you are interested in an email mentor, can help you along too.

First, I don't know how you put the text boxes on the form if it was from the data environment being dragged, or manual.  If your "Properties" window is not available, right-click on any control, then click "Properties..."  Look to the property "ControlSource" and set it to the alias.column you are trying to tie it to.  Do this with each of the fields.

Now, to the buttons.  It LOOKS like you grabbed the "Wizard" style controls, if so, let me know.. different answer will be applied...

If NOT, you can double-click on any "button", the system will bring up a snippet window associated with the "Click" event of buttons, but you could change it to any other available event in the future.  Now, the code.  Whatever you put in this snippet window will be executed when the button is clicked.  So, for each respective button, you may do something like..

```
*/ Code for the TOP button
select YourTable
GO TOP
Thisform.Refresh()

*/ Code for the BOTTOM button
select YourTable
GO BOTTOM
Thisform.Refresh()

*/ For the PREVIOUS button
select YourTable
if NOT BOF()  && BOF() is for Beginning of File
  skip -1
ENDIF
Thisform.Refresh()

*/ For the NEXT button
select YourTable
if NOT EOF()  && EOF() is for END of File
  skip +1
ENDIF
Thisform.Refresh()

*/ Delete button
IF MESSAGEBOX( "Confirm Delete Record?", 36, "Confirm" ) = 6
   */ Delete deletes whatever the CURRENT SINGLE record is,
   */ and is not a full SQL-Delete statement
   DELETE
ENDIF
```

Find, Print, Edit and Delete would be somewhat similar, but what condition to "FIND", you would need to build a report to print. Editing should just be directly available until you add in your own modes of add vs edit vs view mode to handle swapping.

Comment: I can't see any code to bind the data to the textbox controls? :)

Comment: Can you give me your email address, I think I need more help, not only in this question :3

Comment: You don't need code to do the binding. Just set the ControlSource property of the control to the field you want to bind it to.

Comment: @TamarE.Granor, correct, but that is why I directed them to the properties window.  They also wanted to know how to do the buttons, so I put in very basic sample code for the click events.

Comment: Addition short question, If I have Products and Categories (one to many relationship), in the Product detail form, how can I make a combobox for Category selecting?